# CSS form with side by side fields...how to align the labels and fields vertically?

Tags: css, forms

completely frustrated here with something that is probably so simple. I have a form and want the Zip and Zip+4 fields to be on the same line. For some reason nothing is lining up the way I've done it. I've spent the last 6 hours searching the web and trying various things (this latest was from this site) and nothing works. Can someone help me please? Thanks!
Here is my code:

```
<form>
<div style="float:left;"> 
  <label for "StrAddress">Street Address *</label>
<input name="StrAddress" type="text" style="width:200px"  id="StrAddress"  />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "StrSecondaryAddress">Suite, P.O. Box, Apt, Lot</label>
<input name="StrSecondaryAddress" type="text" style="width:200px"  id="StrSecondaryAddress"  />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "StrCity">City *</label>
<input name="StrCity" type="text" class="autosuggestinput"  style="width:200px"  id="StrCity"  />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "subject">State</label>
<input type="text" class="input_text" name="subject" id="subject"/>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="display: inline;;">
<label for "IntZip5">Zip *</label>
<input name="IntZip5" type="text" style="width:100px"  id="IntZip5"  />


<label for "IntZip4">Zip+4</label>
<input type="text" name="IntZip4" id="IntZip4" style="width:50px">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "IntAmount">Taxable Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="IntAmount" id="IntAmount" style="width:150px">

</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Submit Form" />


</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you want in my Firefox, all other label/field combinations are on separate lines and zip and zip+4 are on the same. So, what is your problem?

Comment: sitepoint actually has a great tutorial:http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/fancy-form-design-css just after understanding the concept have a special class for LIs that could contain multiple labels/fields and u r done!

Comment: It looks like you're missing your equals sign in all your label "for" attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/3SmmJ/embedded/result/) do the job for you? Please test it on multiple browsers
because it's only tested on FF 3.6, IE 7+

Comment: That looks great! I will grab it and test it before we put it into use, but that is exactly what I'm looking for. Can't wiat to see how it's done! Many thanks and happy holidays to all who responded!

Comment: also, I would rename the class "multi" to "zip" for example for later reference in JS or CSS if needed.. happy holidays :)

Comment: Please put the solution in your answer instead of simply providing a link.  For example, my router blocks jsfiddle.net as a source of DBDL's (drive-by downloads).

Answer (score 2):

While the structure police are sure to pull me over for this, it is my considered opinion that using a table is the single most reliable way to line up elements in all browsers.  Set the `vertical-align:top` and do what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, but this has to be done using CSS...it's for a government site and I can't use a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along this lines:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
* { padding: 0; margin: 0;} /* do not use universal selector this is just for example */
label {
    width: 300px !important;/* added important to override your inline styles*/
    display: block !important;
    text-align: right !important;
    float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div style="float:left;">
  <label for "StrAddress">Street Address *</label>
<input name="StrAddress" type="text" style="width:200px"  id="StrAddress"  />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "StrSecondaryAddress">Suite, P.O. Box, Apt, Lot</label>
<input name="StrSecondaryAddress" type="text" style="width:200px"  id="StrSecondaryAddress"  />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "StrCity">City *</label>
<input name="StrCity" type="text" class="autosuggestinput"  style="width:200px"  id="StrCity"  />
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "subject">State</label>
<input type="text" class="input_text" name="subject" id="subject"/>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="display: inline;;">
<label for "IntZip5">Zip *</label>
<input name="IntZip5" type="text" style="width:100px"  id="IntZip5"  />


<label for "IntZip4">Zip+4</label>
<input type="text" name="IntZip4" id="IntZip4" style="width:50px">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left;">
<label for "IntAmount">Taxable Amount</label>
<input type="text" name="IntAmount" id="IntAmount" style="width:150px">

</div>
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Submit Form" />


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted shows zip and zip+4 on the same line for me in Firefox, Chrome, and IE.  Can you post a screen shot of how you see it differently and how you want it to look?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...it's working fine, I am just trying to get my input boxes to line up vertically (excluding the zip+4). It seems I either get the fields to all line up and look nice or I get the Zip and Zip+4 on the same line and everything is stair-steppy (a technical term), but can't do both! Thanks again!

Comment: I also tried your code in FF and IE8 (even Quirks Mode and Compatibility View) and got this same display.  IWOMM.